# How can we setup the NUnit Test Runner for WP7 with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, nunit, codeplex

I want to setup the NUnit Test Runner for WP7 with Visual Studio 2010 for unit testing WP7 apps.

I reffered to **http://nunitwindowsphone7.codeplex.com/documentation**  but there is no NUnitTestRunner.dll that has to be referenced in the NUnitTestRunner that i have downloaded from **http://nunitwindowsphone7.codeplex.com/**

Please give any views on this asap.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've simply forgotten to install the [Windows Phone Developer Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13890).

When you do it, your `NUnitTestRunnerWP7.dll` will compile and the tests will work just fine right from Visual Studio.